# Restrict paste in Excel

Tags: excel, excel-2010, vba

I'm working on a protected workbook that only allows users to select and enter data into certain cells.
However, they have a propensity to paste data into these unlocked cells and I want to restrict this behavior in Excel 2010. I found some older VBA code but it seems that the ribbon makes most of it obsolete.

Comment: Have a look at the sheet protection under the "Review" tab in the ribbon.

Comment: I have. Unfortunately there is no lock for only pasting. I can lock entry all together, but I need to allow the users to type in data. But I do not want them pasting into the cells.

Answer (score 1):

You may have to try something like this, I placed these subs in the workbook module

```
Private Sub Workbook_SheetActivate(ByVal Sh As Object)
    Application.CutCopyMode = False

End Sub

Private Sub Workbook_SheetDeactivate(ByVal Sh As Object)
    Application.CutCopyMode = False

End Sub

Private Sub Workbook_SheetBeforeRightClick(ByVal Sh As Object, ByVal Target As Range, Cancel As Boolean)
    Application.CutCopyMode = False

End Sub

Private Sub Workbook_SheetSelectionChange(ByVal Sh As Object, ByVal Target As Range)
    Application.CutCopyMode = False

End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks, I tried option similar to those previously and was unsuccessful. After some digging it seems that they worked until the introduction of the ribbon, but now excel handles everything differently. So they are no long working, at least for me.

Answer (score 0):

I came across the following code that still works in Excel 2010.

```
'*** In a standard module ***
Option Explicit 

Sub ToggleCutCopyAndPaste(Allow As Boolean) 
     'Activate/deactivate cut, copy, paste and pastespecial menu items
    Call EnableMenuItem(21, Allow) ' cut
    Call EnableMenuItem(19, Allow) ' copy
    Call EnableMenuItem(22, Allow) ' paste
    Call EnableMenuItem(755, Allow) ' pastespecial

     'Activate/deactivate drag and drop ability
    Application.CellDragAndDrop = Allow 

     'Activate/deactivate cut, copy, paste and pastespecial shortcut keys
    With Application 
        Select Case Allow 
        Case Is = False 
            .OnKey "^c", "CutCopyPasteDisabled" 
            .OnKey "^v", "CutCopyPasteDisabled" 
            .OnKey "^x", "CutCopyPasteDisabled" 
            .OnKey "+{DEL}", "CutCopyPasteDisabled" 
            .OnKey "^{INSERT}", "CutCopyPasteDisabled" 
        Case Is = True 
            .OnKey "^c" 
            .OnKey "^v" 
            .OnKey "^x" 
            .OnKey "+{DEL}" 
            .OnKey "^{INSERT}" 
        End Select 
    End With 
End Sub 

Sub EnableMenuItem(ctlId As Integer, Enabled As Boolean) 
     'Activate/Deactivate specific menu item
    Dim cBar As CommandBar 
    Dim cBarCtrl As CommandBarControl 
    For Each cBar In Application.CommandBars 
        If cBar.Name <> "Clipboard" Then 
            Set cBarCtrl = cBar.FindControl(ID:=ctlId, recursive:=True) 
            If Not cBarCtrl Is Nothing Then cBarCtrl.Enabled = Enabled 
        End If 
    Next 
End Sub 

Sub CutCopyPasteDisabled() 
     'Inform user that the functions have been disabled
    MsgBox "Sorry!  Cutting, copying and pasting have been disabled in this workbook!" 
    End Sub 

 '*** In the ThisWorkbook Module ***
Option Explicit 

Private Sub Workbook_Activate() 
    Call ToggleCutCopyAndPaste(False) 
End Sub 

Private Sub Workbook_BeforeClose(Cancel As Boolean) 
    Call ToggleCutCopyAndPaste(True) 
End Sub 

Private Sub Workbook_Deactivate() 
    Call ToggleCutCopyAndPaste(True) 
End Sub 

Private Sub Workbook_Open() 
    Call ToggleCutCopyAndPaste(False) 
End Sub
```

The link to the info is: http://www.vbaexpress.com/kb/getarticle.php?kb_id=373